# Errors when Transferring MS Access data to SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server, ssms

My experience with SQL is limited and was hoping someone could give me some advice. 
Needing some suggestions on how to combat the below errors in order to have a successful transfer of an Access database file onto SQL 2014 Express server.

I have been utilising the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to complete this which has returned several errors. A copy of the errors are shown below. 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

•Copying to [dbo].[Tbl_*****] (Error)
 Messages

> ◦Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.
>   An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB
>   record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
>   Server" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "Invalid character value for
>   cast specification.".  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> ◦Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: There was an error with
>   Destination - Tbl_.Inputs[Destination Input].Columns[] on Destination
>   - Tbl_**.Inputs[Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified
>   type.".  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> ◦Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "Destination -
>   Tbl_.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907A
>   occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination -
>   Tbl_.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error
>   occurred on the specified object of the specified component. There may
>   be error messages posted before this with more information about the
>   failure.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> ◦Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput method on component
>   "Destination - Tbl_*****" (115) failed with error code 0xC0209029
>   while processing input "Destination Input" (128). The identified
>   component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is
>   specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the
>   Data Flow task to stop running. There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information about the failure.

(SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

◦Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

◦Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The PrimeOutput method on Source - Tbl_***** returned error code 0xC02020C4. The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Using SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

Comment: Are you moving the data into existing tables, or having the Wizard create new landing tables for you?

Comment: The errors are being quite explicit here; the values can't be implicitly converted to the datatype of the columns in your table. We have no data, and no DDL of your table(s), so there's little more we can offer on on that. Personally, however, I find that sometimes (especially when dealing with poorly controlled/formatted data) that it's easier to treat the whole source data as strings, and insert them into `(n)varchar` columns in a staging table. Then use T-SQL to handle the transformation to the correct datatypes. So, instead of an ETL process, you have an ELT process.

Comment: Eric Brandt : Using the Wizard to create new landing tables. I have tried using varchar for all the data types with max amount for the characters but still no success.